# Disqus comment count for multiple pages

Tags: php, javascript, html, disqus

The following code is to get Disqus counts of comments for multiple pages.

```
var DISQUSWIDGETS;

if (typeof DISQUSWIDGETS != 'undefined') {
    DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount({
        "showReactions":true,
        "text":{
            "and":"and",
            "reactions":{
                "zero":"0 Reactions",
                "multiple":"{num} Reactions",
                "one":"1 Reaction"},
            "comments":{
                "zero":"0 Comments",
                "multiple":"{num} Comments",
                "one":"1 Comment"
            }
        },
        "counts":[
            {"reactions":0,"uid":1,"comments":2},
            {"reactions":0,"uid":2,"comments":5},
            {"reactions":0,"uid":3,"comments":9}
        ]
    });
}
```

I want to get just the number of comments example from here:

`{"reactions":0,"uid":1,"comments":2}` the number of comments should be 2.

Is there any javascript code which will get just the comments?

Comment: What is your criteria for getting the correct line from the "counts" array? Do you want the first one? Do you want the one with id=1?

Comment: Example in first `<a>` will be the comment with `id=1` in second `<a>` the comment with `id=2` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to rewrite this as such:

```
var DISQUSWIDGETS;

if (typeof DISQUSWIDGETS != 'undefined') {
    var disqus_options = {
        "showReactions":true,
        "text":{
            "and":"and",
            "reactions":{
                "zero":"0 Reactions",
                "multiple":"{num} Reactions",
                "one":"1 Reaction"},
            "comments":{
                "zero":"0 Comments",
                "multiple":"{num} Comments",
                "one":"1 Comment"
            }
        },
        "counts":[
            {"reactions":0,"uid":1,"comments":2},
            {"reactions":0,"uid":2,"comments":5},
            {"reactions":0,"uid":3,"comments":9}
        ]
    };
    DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount(disqus_options);
}
```

Then you will be able to access the count like this:

```
disqus_options.counts[0].comments
```

which has the value `2` in this case.

---

**edit**

To filter by `id`, in this case `id == 3`.

```
var counts_with_id = $.grep(disqus_options.counts, function(count) {
    return (count.uid == 3);
});
if (counts_with_id.length) // the id exists
    counts_with_id[0].comments // has value 9
else
    the id does not exist in the disqus_options.
```

---

**edit**

You can "hack" the displayCount method:

```
// Load the disqus plugin which contains the DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount method.

// Change what DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount does.
var actualDisplayCount = DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount;
DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount = function(options) {
    // do things with options
    return actualDisplayCount(options);
};

// Now load the source from http://forum.disqus.com/count-data.js?q=1&1=2,http://www.website.com&2=2
```

Comment: No. I am not able to rewrite because I will get it from URL. In example like this http://forum.disqus.com/count-data.js?q=1&1=2,http://www.website.com&2=2

Comment: If there is not solution with javascript it also can be with `PHP`

Comment: This should be able to do in javascript. I am working on a solution.

Comment: I have updated the answer again. It allows you to use the URL given, but changes how disqus uses the data provided, so you can access it.

Comment: `Load the disqus plugin which contains the DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount method.` I can't understand here, what I need to load?

Comment: Wordpress is probably doing that for you. Here, I mean `<script src="disqus.js">` or whatever it might look like. It's what defines the `DISQUSWIDGETS` object.

Comment: This is what I tried now http://jsfiddle.net/enve/dPwdK/ . But the script doesn't now where to display comment. Can you please make this code to work?